# Is BN_bin2bn from OpenSSL the same as the constructor of Crypto++ Integer that takes a byte array?

Tags: c++, openssl, crypto++

I am trying to port a peice of code on OSX from OpenSSL (which has been removed) to Crypto++ and can't get RSA signature verification to work. I am a bit suspicious about the way the public key is constructed. The existing code decodes base64 values to byte buffers and then uses `BIN_bin2bn` to create modulus and exponent. I fed the same byte buffers to `CrytoPP::Integer` but have some doubts if that is the proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is BN_bin2bn from OpenSSL the same as the constructor of Crypto++ Integer that takes a byte array?

Give or take, yes.

OpenSSL's [`BN_bin2bn`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/BN_bin2bn.html) takes a binary byte array and returns a `BIGNUM`. That's the equivalent to Crypto++ `Integer`. You should show how you are consuming a byte array to ensure you are using it correctly.

Crypto++ [`Integer` constructor](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_integer.html) `Integer (const byte *encodedInteger, size_t byteCount, Signedness sign=UNSIGNED, ByteOrder order=BIG_ENDIAN_ORDER)` is most the same thing as OpenSSL's `BN_bin2bn`. When you take away the default arguments, the ctor is `Integer (const byte *encodedInteger, size_t byteCount)`. You should show how you are consuming a byte array to ensure you are using it correctly.

For completeness, here are the OpenSSL docs from their wiki on [RSA Signing and Verifying](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Signing_and_Verifying). And here is the Crypto++ docs from their  wiki on [RSA Signing and Verifying](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Cryptography).

But as started earlier, you should show your code. There's not much we can do with the description of your algorithms.

Comment: thanks for confirming that my choice was correct, I actually found that the verification was failing due to other issues, but at least I now have external approval that I am doing this right, since the examples in crypto++ page showed public key construction from C-style strings.